# Flutter Web : Execute an action on Physical Keyboard Key Press

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter Web, I am displaying a popup with two actions "Cancel" & "Confirm". Usually, Pressing the ESC key on the physical keyboard dismissed the popup out of the box. I want to execute the Confirm functionality by Pressing the ENTER key on the physical keyboard.

I took the RawKeyboardListener approach and it didn't seem to work. Below is my attempt.

```
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return RawKeyboardListener(
          focusNode: FocusNode(),
          onKey: (RawKeyEvent event){
            print("keyboard key is pressed");
            if(event.isControlPressed){
              print('controlled pressed');
            }
            if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
              print('Pressed Key: ${event.logicalKey.debugName}');
            }
            if(event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)){
              print("Enter is pressed");
            }
          },
          child: DialogSimple(
            title: "Delete Category?",
            message:
            "Do you really want to delete this category?. You cannot undo this action.",
            actions: [
              BtnTextAccent(
                text: "Cancel",
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              ),
              BtnTextAccent(
                text: "Delete",
                textColor: AppColors.dangerColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  cubit.deleteCategory(item.id);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      });
```

With the code above it doesn't event detect any key press event. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating your instance of FocusNode directly in your showDialog method, create an instance directly in your stateful widget (don't forget to dispose it)

```dart
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Then, request for focus before returning your RawKeyboardListener widget:

```dart
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          Future.microtask(() => _focusNode.requestFocus());
          return RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            onKey: (RawKeyEvent event){
              print("keyboard key is pressed");
              if(event.isControlPressed){
                print('controlled pressed');
              }
              if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
                print('Pressed Key: ${event.logicalKey.debugName}');
              }
              if(event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)){
                print("Enter is pressed");
              }
            },
            child: ... whatever child you want to put in there
```

Comment: oh, I was missing _focusNode.requestFocus(). Thanks!